# How to open multiple dialog components on the same page that loads separate tables using SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, modal-dialog, svelte, sveltekit

Say on a page I have two buttons which in themselves are components

`<Button callFunction={() => dialog.showModal()}>Check Records</Button>`

each opens a `<Dialog>` component. Each button is calling a function to show a modal and currently both are showing the same table. What do I need to implement to ensure each button on the page opens tableA and tableB respectively?

I use `showModal = false` at the start and my dialog component in use on the page would be like this:

```
{#if showModal}
    <Dialog bind:dialog on:close={() => console.log('closed')}>
        <table>tableA</table>
    </Dialog>
{/if}
```

I had tried to use a method that involves a variable per dialog to open, `showModal1 = false` and `showModal2 = false` then use those variables in the `{#if}` blocks to open the modals with separate tables on but that clearly didn't work. I cannot change `dialog.showModal()` in the button as it's required as part of the `<dialog>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not quite compute:

> I cannot change `dialog.showModal()` in the button as it's required as part of the `<dialog>` tag.

`bind:dialog` is just a shorthand for `bind:dialog={dialog}`, so you can very well do:

```js
let showDialogA = false;
let dialogA: Dialog;
let showDialogB = false;
let dialogB: Dialog;
```

```html
{#if showDialogA}
  <Dialog bind:dialog={dialogA} ...
{/if}
{#if showDialogB}
  <Dialog bind:dialog={dialogB} ...
{/if}
```

(Are the `#if` even necessary when you additionally need to call `showModal`?)

---

Often one can also just not do that and create a component [in code](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api) instead, parameterized via properties. E.g.

```js
function showTableDialog(table) {
  const dialog = new TableDialog({
    target: document.body,
    props: { table },
  });
  dialog.$on('close', () => dialog.$destroy());

  dialog.showModal();
}
```

(`TableDialog` would wrap a `Dialog` internally and render the `table` data.)

There is less state to worry about and also no reset/cleanup required if there are inputs in the dialog; everything gets destroyed on close and a new one is created every time.

If one needs to read data from the dialog properties, the [`accessors` option](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-options) can be set.